# Checksum identification

Tags: checksum

I'm trying to understand some data traffic.

Here are some short packages I captured (Hex string):

```
Data      Checksum
------    ---------
87          0087
7639        7639
7739        7739
DA423030    A25A
DA423031    A25B
DA423130    A35A
DA424030    D25A
DA423040    A22A
DA423032    A258
```

Can anyone identify how the checksum is made up?

(Note: Adding zero-bytes at the beginning of the data does not change the checksum, but adding them at the end does change it.)

Comment: any other input? can you give the checksum for 7739 or DA423031?

Comment: I have updated the question for your request (by several attempts). If need be, I can check more

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still too difficult with the specific data. I've been trying to get to the algorithm with something like this: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4460/guessing-crc-checksum-algorithm but there are still a lot of missing variables. you can post your question over there and maybe someone will be able to help you

Comment: @KokoJumbo thanks to you I thought of running CRC-16 types on only part of the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is:

1. Take the whole string **up to** the last 2 bytes, perform on it CRC-16/XMODEM.
2. Perform on the result XOR with the last 2 bytes left.

For example:

```
Data      Checksum
------    ---------
DA423030    A25A

DA42 >> CRC-16/XMODEM >> 926A
926A >> XOR With 3030 >> A25A
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who tried to solve and helped, also to @Koko Jumbo.